# How to return a bitmap that has been drawn on top of?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have class allows you draw on an image from the filesystem. It has methods that I've shared below. The idea is that, as the image is touched, circles will be drawn on top of that image at each of the points that have been touched.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    try{
        if (mTextPaint == null)
        {
            mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mTextPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        }

        if (cachedBitmap == null)
        {
            Bitmap immutableBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(CameraActivity.getFile()));
            cachedBitmap = immutableBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        }
        if (cachedCanvas == null)
        {
            cachedCanvas = canvas;
            cachedCanvas.setBitmap(cachedBitmap);
        }
        if (! mPoints.isEmpty())
        {
            for (Point point : mPoints)
            {
                cachedCanvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 25, mTextPaint);
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Drawing points...");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error on draw: " + e.toString());
    }

}

/**
 * populates a list of points that have been touched
 *
 * @param event
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    Point point = new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
    mPoints.add(point);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

After this is done, I'd like to include a static method that returns the now drawn on bitmap, something like this:

```
public static Bitmap getCachedBitmap()
{
    return cachedBitmap;
}
```

The problem is, the `cachedBitmap` variable is not being updated as it is being drawn on, so when I inspect the return value of `cachedBitmap`, I just get the Bitmap from the file URI specified in the initial `immutableBitmap` variable.

Any idea how I can return the altered bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

You can take an image of outer layout which contains both the bitmap and the canvas on which circles are drawn:

```
View v = yourlayout.getRootView();
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
BitmapDrawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

By this way, you will get your initial image + edits.

Comment: When I do this, I get `bitmap == null ` from `v.getDrawingCache()`. However, within `v`, `cachedCanvas` is not null and nor is `mPoints`. I feel like I am close, but not quite there yet because the info is still in a Canvas, not a Bitmap

Comment: I am now able to get an empty bitmap from this. It is the correct size and shape, but does not contain any of the points that I drew. Any ideas?